# Fatal error: Class '\PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory' not found

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm first in using Paypal REST SDK when I want to create a payment. This error occurs.

Fatal error: Class '\PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory' not found in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalLoggingManager.php on line 62

The error occurs while executing this code.

```
try {
  $payment->create($apiContext);

  // Get PayPal redirect URL and redirect the customer
  $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

  // Redirect the customer to $approvalUrl
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  echo $ex->getCode();
  echo $ex->getData();
  die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  die($ex);
}
```

How to solve this problem ??
** SDK version 1.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Line 62 contains the code $factoryInstance->getLogger($loggerName)

```
         private function __construct($loggerName)
    {
        $config = PayPalConfigManager::getInstance()->getConfigHashmap();
        // Checks if custom factory defined, and is it an implementation of @PayPalLogFactory
        $factory = array_key_exists('log.AdapterFactory', $config) && in_array('PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory', class_implements($config['log.AdapterFactory'])) ? $config['log.AdapterFactory'] : '\PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory';
        /** @var PayPalLogFactory $factoryInstance */
        $factoryInstance = new $factory();
        $this->logger = $factoryInstance->getLogger($loggerName);
        $this->loggerName = $loggerName;
    }
```

If you look further up the code it is looking for the 'log.AdapterFactory' setting. This is normally not included in your ApiContext settings located in your config file.

Insert the log.AdapterFactory setting into your ApiContext settings located in your config file or bootstrap file whichever you have decided to create.

This is normally associated with the AdapterFactory that you are using.

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php) is a very useful sample from the Github Repository illustrating the various settings that you can use with the new logger feature available in PayPal. Look in particular at line 94

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
        array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE `INFO` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
            'cache.enabled' => true,
            //'cache.FileName' => '/PaypalCache' // for determining paypal cache directory
            // 'http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 30
            // 'http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id' => '123123123'
            //'log.AdapterFactory' => '\PayPal\Log\DefaultLogFactory' // Factory class implementing \PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory
        )
    );
```

You will normally also have to create a Class MonologLogFactory using the official Paypal recommendations [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Custom-Logger). Remember to include a suitable namespace at the top of your file relative to path/folder/file/location. Here is the code from Paypal:

```
use PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class MonologLogFactory implements PayPalLogFactory
    {

        /**
         * Returns logger instance implementing LoggerInterface.
         *
         * @param string $className
         * @return LoggerInterface instance of logger object implementing LoggerInterface
         */
        public function getLogger($className)
        {
            $logger = new Monolog\Logger($className);
            $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler("mail.log"));

            return $logger;
        }
    }
```

If you are still encountering problems double check that you actually have the file located in C:\wamp32\www\projectfoldername\web\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Log\PayPalDefaultLogFactory on your testing platform. I am using wampserver.

If the file is not located here ensure that your composer.json file has  "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*" under it and then update composer.